# Re-Declaring/Redefining Java Variables Loop

Tags: java, scope, instance-variables, do-loops

I know it's recommended to declare variable in narrowest scope possible, but what if the variable needs to be redefined inside the loop, and then that result is the one that needs to be used afterwards.  Example code below in a do while loop.

```
        OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass();
        SomeClass someClass;
        long timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1500;

        boolean isExpectedUser;
        do {
            someClass = otherClass.getWhateverList.get(0);
            isExpectedUser = someClass.getUser().equals(userWanted);
        } while (!isExpectedUser && System.currentTimeMillis() < timeout);

        String uiStartTime = someClass.getTime();
        assertNotNull(uiStartTime, "String");
```

Comment: Your code is fine. You are declaring it in the narrowest scope already since it is needed after the loop.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't sure if the redefined variable someClass inside the loop was the one that would now be used for uiStartTime, but it appears so